# Increasing Font-size without breaking the layout

Tags: css, sass, anchor

I'm trying to increase the font-size of an anchor when hovered but it's moving the other tags down, increasing the div size and thus breaking my layout ( It's a grid with multiple equal divs )

Right now it looks like this:

```
.player{
background-color:aliceblue;
border: solid 1px black;
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    &:hover{
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: transparent;
        font-size: 36px;
    }
  }
}
```

Obs: It's SASS but general css rules apply ( I hope )
Visually it looks like this when not hovered:
[image: Not hovered a tag]

And it looks like this when hovered:
[image: Hovered tag]

I've tried with `z-index` but it didn't work. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issue, only post the compiled CSS.